# Mp3 file is null using taglib(c++)

Tags: c++, taglib

I am using taglib in c++ to change metadata from mp3 files. I have written a code that works great. But I found a MP3 file that cannot open with taglib.

The MP3 file has tags. I can see them with Vlc media player and MediaInfo and with explorer.exe.

I try this minimum codes but it say that the file is not valid.

```
TagLib::FileRef filer("file.mp3");
        if(filer.isNull())
            cout <<"null";
```

or this code:

```
TagLib::MPEG::File fileMpeg("file.mp3");
if(!fileMpeg.isValid())
{
   cout << "file not valid";
}
```

other files work but not that one.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it that specific file.mp3 thats failing, but others work? I had an issue with Winamp once, there was 1 mp3 file that when scanned caused it to crash, everything else was fine.

Comment: In fact, there is some mp3 file that works and others are null. I don't know why. but the most mp3 files work.

Comment: I just convert a mp3 file that doesn't work to a new mp3 file. That new mp3 file works and TagLib detects that it has id3v2 Tag with the same tags but the other one still null.

Comment: I believe that was the problem with me, something i the tags was strange. Cleared it all and I think it worked after that,

Comment: The problem is that, TagLib cannot open the file. How can I clear it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, The problem was not from the files but, from the files name or directory.
To fix the problem I sand `cont wchar_t*` rather than `const char*` because the files that I tried to open contain french characters from ISO or unicode encoding but not from ASCII.